# Decoding only some PCM bytes at a time from an mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, mp3, inputstream, decoder

How do I decode something on the order of a 1000 bytes of PCM audio from an mp3 file, without decoding the whole thing?

I need to mix together four to six tracks, to one, so that they're played simultaneously on an AudioTrack in the Android app.

This can be done if I can get a stream of PCM samples, and so simple add the decoded tracks together (and maybe adjust for clipping and volume), and then write them to an AudioTrack buffer.

That part is simple.

But how do I decode the individual mp3 files, to inputstreams I can get byte arrays from? I've found something called JLayer, but its not quite clear to me how to do this.

I'd rather avoid doing it in C++ (I'm a bit rusty, and my team doesn't like it), though if that's needed I can do it. Though I'd need a short example of how get say 240 decoded bytes from a file via mpg123, or other such libraries.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest you can do is 576 samples, which is the smallest MP3 frame size.  However, most MP3 streams use the bit reservoir meaning you likely have to decode frames around the frame you want to decode as well.

Complicating things further, bare MP3 streams don't have any internal timestamping, so if you want to drop accurately in the middle of a file, you have to decode up until that point.  (MP3 frame headers don't contain byte lengths, so you can't just skim frame headers accurately.)  You *can* try to needle-drop into the middle of the file based on byte length, but this isn't an accurate way of seeking and can be off by several seconds, even for CBR.  For VBR, it's all over the place.

It sounds like all you need to do is have a stream decoder, so that the decoding happens as playback is occurring.  I'm no Android developer, but it seems you can just use AudioTrack from the framework, in streaming mode.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html  And then the MediaCodec to actually do the decoding.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html  Android devices support MP3, so you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: I forgot to give a like for this answer. It didn't answer my question and I'm not longer working on this project, but its good food for thought.

Comment: However I do remember that doing it in native Java code is out of the question. I'd need to do it in C++, as working with multiple audio streams in Java is highly problematic on Android phones.